# Как вытянуть данные из отключенной базы данных?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, denwer

Есть старая база данных, осталась от *Denwer*. После переустановки ОС на *Ubuntu* появилась необходимость восстановить дамп базы данных.

Как вытянуть данные со старой **отключенной** базы *mysql*?

Comment: PhpMyAdmin — это просто веб-приложение, написанное на PHP, которое предоставляет удобный веб-интерфейс для администрирования MySQL. Если у вас остался только PhpMyAdmin, то толку от него мало. Ежели есть сами базы, то можно попробовать их подключить к СУБД и тогда даже дамп не нужно будет делать.

Comment: ок я попробую только не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Попробуйте вариант из ответа @AlexanderBarakin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

обычно достаточно скопировать файлы: [Making Backups by Copying Table Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html#idm140713154067824).

попробуйте создать новую пустую базу данных и скопировать все файлы (*.frm, *.MYD, и *.MYI) в её каталог (не забыв выставить у них необходимого владельца и права, по аналогии с другими базами, лежащими в соседних каталогах). каталог (с названием, совпадающим с названием базы данных) по умолчанию будет находиться в каталоге `/var/lib/mysql/`.

после копирования имеет смысл рестартовать *субд*:

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

теперь к базе данных можно будет подключиться (от имени пользователя `root` *mysql*, или назначив нужные полномочия другому пользователю) и сделать дамп.

Comment: я нашел где в denwer лежат эти файлы,  но вот на ubuntu не могу разобраться со структурой каталогов где в них лежат эти файлы

Comment: я добавлял эту информацию в ответ. перечитайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: а все ок )) только они не там находились  а в папке /users/admin/sfdik43555fg09/mysql

Comment: чувствуется тяжёлая рука админа-bsd-шника (улыбка).

Comment: спасибо за помощь ))